# Pyro4 python module working flow and its applications

Tags: python, service, web-applications, pyro4

I have deployed my Python application as a service using Pyro4 module of python.
its using nameserver as localhost:9090

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('python -m Pyro4.naming',shell=True)
import myapp
# Pyro ..
import Pyro4
```

I would like to have suggestion.My application is like a service which should running as a windows service.
Application is processing list of strings and returning the processed python dictionary object.but when i am processing in as 500 accurances and then it is getting hanged. what can i do to avoid this hangness, is there any configuration changes to be made? or any other thing can solve my problem? Kindly suggest.
Thanks VM:)